# mongoose sort by a function

Tags: sorting, mongoose

I have a schema that looks like this

```
var user = new Schema({
  preference1: { // preference is a number between 1 - 10
    type: Number 
  },
  preference2: { // preference is a number between 1 - 10
    type: Number 
  }
})
```

how do I find the documents and sort by a function on the preferences fields? Say `fn` is something like this

`fn = Math.abs(preference1 - 3) + preference2 ^ 2`

Answer (score 2):

I kind of find a temporary solution. It works but isn't really what I was looking for... the code is really messy and apparently you cannot take arbitrary `fn` for sorting..

for example, say `fn = (a+3) * (b+5)`

```
Media.aggregate()
.project({
     "type": 1,
     "status": 1,
     "newField1": { "$add": [ "$type", 3 ] },
     "newField2": { "$add": [ 5, "$status" ] },
})
.project({
     "newField3": { "$multiply": [ "$newField1", "$newField2" ] },
})
.sort("newField3")
.exec()
```